# Can PDO return dates as DateTime objects?

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, pdo

Microsoft's SQL Server driver for PHP can return dates as native PHP DateTime objects, but when accessed via PDO, dates are returned as strings. Is there any way to configure PDO to return dates as objects as well?

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS';
$database = 'MyDatabase';
$username = 'MyUsername';
$password = 'MyPassword';
$sql = 'SELECT CAST(\'2017-01-31\' AS DATE) AS [Col1], \'2017-01-31\' AS [Col2]';

// Microsoft driver
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,
                       ['UID' => $username, 'PWD' => $password, 'Database' => $database,]);
$statement = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);
sqlsrv_execute($statement);
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($statement, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row);
}
/*
array (size=2)
  'Col1' => 
    object(DateTime)[1]
      public 'date' => string '2017-01-31 00:00:00.000000' (length=26)
      public 'timezone_type' => int 3
      public 'timezone' => string 'Australia/Canberra' (length=18)
  'Col2' => string '2017-01-31' (length=10)
*/

// PDO
$pdo_conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server={$server};Database={$database}", $username, $password);
foreach ($pdo_conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
/*
array (size=4)
  'Col1' => string '2017-01-31' (length=10)
  0 => string '2017-01-31' (length=10)
  'Col2' => string '2017-01-31' (length=10)
  1 => string '2017-01-31' (length=10)
*/
```

Microsoft's driver can distinguish between the date and text columns, while, apparently, PDO can't. It even includes the time zone! As the code stands, with PDO, after the query has run, the PHP code needs to know that `Col1` (but not `Col2` which contains an identical string) is supposed to be a DateTime object and manually convert it. Since the database already knows the type of the field, regardless of whether it is pulled straight out of a table or is the result of a calculation, is there any way to access this information in PDO as well?

Comment: Cast your new array to object.

Comment: There isn't. Even if there were, which time zone would PDO use to supply to DateTime? That's why you can create a wrapper around PDO, much like popular PHP ORM's do, and transform the field according to your needs.